# How does Titanium Backup install applications without using the package manager and prompt?

Tags: android

Installation of APK usually brings up the package manager that shows the list of permissions etc. Titanium backup doesn't do this; it justs handles the restore in the background, even with hundred of apps.

It would have to copy the apk file to /data/app/, copy data files to /data/data//

What else? Updating of permissions? Notifying launcher of change? Is there an easy way to do all this, handled by the system, but without requiring the user to intervene manually?

Answer (score 0):

For Titanium Backup to do those things, it must have root access (superuser) to the device. That, in short, is how it is capable of writing data to those protected locations.

Comment: Yes, I have knowledge on running rooted commands within my application. I want to install an app remotely by sending the apk file over to the device. After that, I have no idea how to continue.